# Reading file from Azure blob storage using pickle or dill without saving to disk

Tags: azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, pickle, dill

I'm trying to read weights for a machine learning model from Azure Storage Blob in Python. This should be running in Azure Functions, so I don't believe I'm able to use methods which save the blob to disk.

I'm using azure-storage-blob 12.5.0, not the legacy version.

I've tried using *Dill.loads* to load the .pkl file, like so:

```python
connection_string = 'my_connection_string'
blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, blob_name)
downloader = blob_client.download_blob(0)

with BytesIO() as f:
    downloader.readinto(f)
    weights = dill.loads(f)
```

Which returns:

```
>>> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'
```

I'm not sure how the approach using Pickle would be. How could this be solved?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is how this problem was solved:

```python
def get_weights_blob(blob_name):
    connection_string = 'my_connection_string'
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, container_name, blob_name)
    downloader = blob_client.download_blob(0)

    # Load to pickle
    b = downloader.readall()
    weights = pickle.loads(b)

    return weights
```

And then retrieving weights by using the function:

```python
weights = get_weights_blob(blob_name = 'myPickleFile')
```

Comment: Thanks! Saved me a lot of iterations :)

Answer (score 0):

This is my working sample

```
def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:

 connection_string = ''
    blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string, 'blog-storage-containe', 'blobfile')
    downloader = blob_client.download_blob(0)

b = downloader.readall()
loaded_model = pickle.loads(b)
```

And requirements.txt file

```
azure-functions
numpy
joblib
azure-storage-blob
sklearn
```

Comment: If that is supposed to be Python code, it is not valid Python code (indentation).